# JQuery Select Input Fields Except Hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a row in a table which contains a checkbox and some other form fields (text boxes, hidden fields, select lists). When the checkbox is checked I want to disable all form fields in that row except for the hidden fields. I have this working for the most part, but I can't seem to ignore the hidden fields.

What is the best way to select all form fields in a table row but ignore hidden fields in the selection?

Answer (score 73):

```
$(":input:not([type=hidden])")
```

":input" is a jQuery pseudo selector... "Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements."
http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 47):

Assuming by "hidden" you mean `type="hidden"` ie:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
```

then you can use the [attribute not equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) to do this:

```
$("tr input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var cb = $(this);
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  if (cb.val()) {
    tr.find("input[type!='hidden']").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    tr.find("input[type!='hidden']").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

My general advice is avoid attribute selectors. They're slow. Give the relevant inputs (either the hidden ones or the not hidden ones) a class and then use that in the selectors.

If however you mean "hidden" as in "not visible" then use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$("tr input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var cb = $(this);
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  if (cb.val()) {
    tr.find("input:visible").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    tr.find("input:visible").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: @Cletus do you think that a filter() call with a function that checked whether "this.type" is "hidden" would be faster than the in-selector attribute test?

Comment: Ahhh, never even thought of tagging them with a class. Nice!

Comment: @cletus - Excellent tip on using classes. Just made my life worthwhile.

Comment: `"input[type!=hidden]"`, i.e. without inner apostrophes, works too.

Answer (score 27):

You can also solve this using the hidden selector

`$("input:not(:hidden)")`

See also: [jQuery hidden selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 6):

I found a simple way of doing this in jquery.

```
$("tr input").not("input[type='hidden']")
```

In code snippet below, there is a div with an id of `tabsDiv` that contains multiple html elements and this code gets all input elements inside this div except those with type of `hidden`.

```
$("#tabsDiv").find("input").not("input[type='hidden']")
```

Answer (score 1):

.........

```
$('tr input').attr('disabled', true)
$('tr input[type="hidden"]').removeAttr('disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tag your "selector" checkbox (e.g. with a class attribute "selector) so that it is clear that it is used for checking instead of regular form element. Then you use this:

```
$('table :checkbox.selector').click(function(ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget)
            .parents('td').siblings('td')
            .find(':input:not([type=hidden])')
            .attr('disabled', ev.currentTarget.checked);
});
```

This solution works for all inputs (eg. select lists, textareas) and it doesn't disable the selector checkbox itself.

I'm assuming you use latest jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a filter of visible  which means it will take only input element which are visible to users.
This worked for me I am adding description for 30 char.

$("input:visible")

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it worked fine for me:

```
var $inputs = $('#formArticle :input:not(:hidden)');
```

`formArticle` is my form name.